# Deletion of node from linked list

Tags: c++

I am trying to code for deletion of a node with k as data of linked list. The below program is running fine, but it is not giving desired output if we have to delete the head node. For example, if the linked list is 98->6->1 and I have to delete 98, then the output which the program is showing is 0->6->1. Except for the deletion of the head node, it is working correctly for all other cases.
Below is the c++ code for the same.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;


class Node
{
    public :
           int data;
           Node* next;
   };

Node * insert(Node* head, int data) {
  Node* new_node= new Node();
  new_node->data = data;
  new_node->next = head;
  head = new_node;
  return head;
 }

  void deleteNode(Node *head, int key)
  {
     Node *temp = head;
     Node *prev = NULL;
     if(temp!=NULL && temp->data==key){
     head = temp->next;
     delete temp;
   }
    else{
        while(temp!=NULL && temp->data!=key){
          prev = temp;
          temp = temp->next;
    }
    if(temp == NULL){
        return;
    }
    prev->next = temp->next;
    delete temp;
   }
   }


    void display(Node * head) {

    while(head != NULL)
   {
    cout<<head->data<<" ";
    head = head->next;
   }
  }

   int main() {
   Node * head = NULL;

   head = insert(head, 1);

   head=insert(head,6);
   head=insert(head,98);
   deleteNode(head,98);
   display(head);

   return 0;
  }
```

Comment: See [how to delete head in a linked list in c?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59922001/3422102) (PS, since this is C++, you can pass head as a reference and make that work)

Comment: More handy reading: [How do I properly delete nodes of linked list in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22121257/how-do-i-properly-delete-nodes-of-linked-list-in-c) Pay special attention to the pointer-to-pointer trick in the community addition.

Comment: Whatever resource you're using to learn C++ I would say it's not very good. You don't use the power of C++ by using more classes and member functions. You also have a couple of bad habits, one which is considered really bad ([that header file inclusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)).

Comment: I think people just use that include to spite us.

Comment: I thing that you are creating a circular list with this

Node * insert(Node* head, int data) {
  Node* new_node= new Node();
  new_node->data = data;
  new_node->next = head;
  head = new_node;
  return head;
 }

Comment: By using `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`, you have included every single header, instead of just having `#include <iostream>`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thank you for pointing my mistake. Apart from header file inclusion kindly mention my mistake if any, that would be really helpful.TIA

Comment: By the way, please read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake in your code is that the head you are passing to deleteNode function is by value so the changes made to the head function is not displayed. The head in your function is not the same head in your main function it is just the copy of that head, so to apply the same change being applied to the head in deletenode function to the original head, you have to pass the address of the head(or pass by reference).

Editing in your code-
I have applied changes in deleteNode function first five lines and the third last line when you are passing value by reference `deleteNode(&head,98);`

Edited code-

```
    #include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;


class Node
{
    public :
           int data;
           Node* next;
   };

Node * insert(Node* head, int data) {
  Node* new_node= new Node();
  new_node->data = data;
  new_node->next = head;
  head = new_node;
  return head;
 }

  void deleteNode(Node **head, int key)
  {
     Node *temp = *head;
     Node *prev = NULL;
     if(temp!=NULL && temp->data==key){
     *head = temp->next;
     temp->next = NULL;
     delete temp;
   }
    else{
        while(temp!=NULL && temp->data!=key){
          prev = temp;
          temp = temp->next;
    }
    if(temp == NULL){
        return;
    }
    prev->next = temp->next;
   // temp->next = NULL;
    delete temp;
   }
   }


    void display(Node * head) {

    while(head != NULL)
   {
    cout<<head->data<<" ";
    head = head->next;
   }
  }

   int main() {
   Node * head = NULL;

   head = insert(head, 1);

   head=insert(head,6);
   head=insert(head,98);
   deleteNode(&head,98);
   display(head);

   return 0;
  }
```

Now if you run the above code the output you will get after deleting node of value 98 will be 6->1.
Hope you will find it helpful.

Comment: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: And you're not really passing by reference in the `deleteNode` function, you're passing a pointer which is the old C-way to *emulate* pass by reference. C++ have native references. You also don't need to repeat unmodified code. And just browsing the code it's hard to see when and where you have modified it.

Comment: there i want to say you can also do it by call by reference. I am a new to this site i will take care about it next time

Answer (score 3):

In `deleteNode()`, you are passing in the `head` node *by value*, so any modification made to it is not reflected back to the caller. You need to either `return` the new `head`, like you do with `Insert()`, or else you need to pass in the `head` by reference:

```
void deleteNode(Node* &head, int key)
```